# Pasting executes command in unix

Tags: linux, terminal

Sometimes in Unix kind of Operating Systems, just pasting a command in terminal executes the command instead of pasting and hitting enter. Is there a special reason for this behaviour ? Why is this useful ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful on *how* you copy (highlight) the command. If you go past the end of the command (or the next line), you are also copying the newline, so when you paste it, you'll get the newline acting like the `<enter>` key.

Once you know that, this feature can actually be quite nice .. especially if you *do* want the command to execute each time you paste.

Comment: By comparison, Windows console windows never copy the newline for the last line of the selection. You can sometimes work around that if there is a blank line after the last line you want to copy.

Answer (score 3):

You pasted a newline character with it which executes the command